# CSS/LESS if more then one element

Tags: css, if-statement, less

Is there any way, of having a `if` like syntax, where I can check (for an example) there are more than `input[type="text"]`

Something like:

```
.my-element >= 1 {
   border: 1px solid red; // Each .my-element will have a red border
}

.my-lement == 1 {
   border: 1px solid green; // The only .my-element will have a green border
}
```

In javascript I would do something like:

```
if ($('input[type="text"]').length >= 1)
```

I mentioned LESS in the title, because I'm writing my css code in a LESS syntax

Comment: No. CSS is not designed to perform the logic.

Comment: Please explain your question clearly. Unable to identify your exact need.

Comment: This is called a parent selector, which CSS currently does not have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, in some cases, approximate this (albeit it requires an up-to-date browser, compliant with CSS3):

```
input {
    border-color: #f00;
}

input:only-of-type {
    border-color: #0f0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cshX3/).

The above works on the assumption that you're trying to style an `input` element which is the *only* `input` element (or 'element of that type') as a child of its parent (it has no siblings of the same `input` element-type).

If, however, you're trying to style an element differently according to whether it has *any* sibling elements, you can use:

```
input {
    border-color: #f00;
}

input:only-child {
    border-color: #0f0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cshX3/1/).

References:

- [`:only-of-type` (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aonly-of-type).
- [`:only-of-type` (W3C.org)](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#only-of-type-pseudo).

Answer (score 2):

**NO**, in CSS there is no `if else` . Use `JavaScript` for changing your `css` dynamically.

the `if` statement is **not** present in `LESS` as well. But this language supports guard expression which may help in mimicking some if statements.

[Check this tutorial](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/26/pattern-matching-and-guards-in-less-stylesheets/)